# Using model as public in repository

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, model, repository

I'm using Laravel framework and I tried to work with it and I found some disturbing issue.

As I was told, I should create repositories that does the whole data management. but the Eloquent does it so much easier and if I create functions like `get()` or `getByAttr()` on the repositories It's pretty much doing what the Eloquent does.. It's even limits me.

So I thought, why shouldn't I set the `$model` as `public` and then I can just use `$repository->model->Eloquent()` and if have some complicated function I'll just code it in the `repository`.

Is it a bad idea? and if it does, please explain why. And if there's some better way, I'll be happy to know about it.

Comment: I wish you the best of luck with your question, but I don't think I'd classify this as "some disturbing issue"... :)

Comment: @JoelHinz it is, because I can do so much with the Eloquent and it'll be foolish of me to create a method that is already created..

Answer (score 1):

Thats the point of the repository is that its dealing with the querying of data and you're using the repositories interface to do that. By using repositories you're abstracting away the controller from the data.

For example, if you used Eloquent directly in your controllers (as you're wanting to do in your question) then if at some point you decide not to use eloquent in the future you would need to rewrite each and everyone of your controllers to use the new ORM (or w/e you're using). By using a repository you would just need to rewrite the repository implementation to use the new ORM and nothing more.

This post gives an in-depth look at the repository pattern http://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/